# Proof of $(A+B)\cdot C = AC+BC$

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

I'd appreciate it if somebody could check over my proof using matrix multiplication and addition, for errors or what could be improved etc.
The question is: Let $A,B \in R^{m\times n}$ and $C \in R^{n\times p}$

Prove using matrix multiplication and addition that: $(A+B)\cdot C=AC+BC$

Here is my attempt:

LHS: Let $(A+B)\cdot C = D$

$d_{ij}=($row $i$ of $A+B)\cdot ($column $j$ of $C)$

$A=(a_{i\times j})_{m\times p}$   $B=(b_{i\times j})_{m\times p}$ $C=(c_{i\times j})_{m\times p}$

Row $i$ of $A+B =($row $i$ of $A)+($row $i$ of $B)$

$=(a_{i1}+a_{i2}...+a_{ip})+(b_{i1}+b_{i2}...+b_{ip})$

$=(a_{i1}+b_{i1}+a_{i2}+b_{i2}...+a_{ip}+b_{ip})$

$d_{ij}=((a_{i1}+b_{i1})\cdot c_{j1}+(a_{i2}+b_{i2})\cdot c_{j2}...+(a_{ip}+b_{ip})\cdot c_{jp})$

$=(a_{i1}\cdot c_{j1}+b_{i1}\cdot c_{j1}+a_{i2}\cdot c_{j2}+b_{i2}\cdot c_{j2}...+a_{ip}\cdot c_{jp}+b_{ip}\cdot c_{jp})$

$=(a_{i1}\cdot c_{j1}+a_{i2}\cdot c_{j2}...+a_{ip}\cdot c_{jp})+(b_{i1}\cdot c_{j1}+b_{i2}\cdot c_{j2}...+b_{ip}\cdot c_{jp})$

$=($row $i$ of $A)\cdot ($column $j$ of $C)+($row $i$ of $B)\cdot ($column $j$ of $C)$

$\therefore D = AC+BC = RHS$

$(A+B)\cdot C=AC+BC$

Comment: Why would you *not* use summation symbols for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the cell $i,j$, noting that obviously four two matrices $D$ and $E$ of same dimensions, $D_{i,j} + E_{i,j} = (D+E)_{i,j}$ (by definition), and using the definition of matrix product, you have:

\begin{align}
((A + B) \cdot C)_{i,j} &= \sum_{k=1}^n (A+B)_{i,k} \cdot C_{k,j}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (A_{i,k}+B_{i,k}) \cdot C_{k,j}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left((A_{i,k} \cdot C_{k,j}) + (B_{i,k} \cdot C_{k,j})\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (A_{i,k} \cdot C_{k,j}) + \sum_{k=1}^n(B_{i,k} \cdot C_{k,j})\\
&=(A\cdot C)_{i,j} + (B \cdot C)_{i,j} = (A \cdot C + B \cdot C)_{i,j}.
\end{align}